# How to call methods from other classes not having an instance?

Tags: java, oop, gwt

How can I call a method from a class that is not an object within another class, and has nothing in common with this other class?

In my case:

```
class GridUI {
    com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid grid;

    public void refresh() {
         dataGrid.redraw();
    }
}

class SomeBackendService() {
   public foo() {
      //have to trigger refresh of a specific grid
   }
}
```

One possibility might be to make the `refresh()` and `grid` `static`. But that's bad design, and I cannot use this approach as I want to use several implementations of `GridUI`.

So, how can I refresh a certain gridclass in my app from any service that does not contain this grid as an object??

Comment: You could make a singleton 'container' for your grids, which your backend service could query.

Comment: Well, which instance of GridUI would you refresh?

Comment: well uhm... either do static or pass those objects as params. What other ways do you see/feel? Edit: normally you tell your render-window (gui) what actors belong to it and call an update on the gui when required

Comment: I think the best approach for this kind of problem is event programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively create a components registry  (basically a `Map<String,Grid>`), then fetch the grid from `SomeBackendService` using its id as key in the registry.  (I guess you know which grid you want to refresh, right?)

Be careful with registries though:

- make sure they are thread safe if need be (probably true in an UI app)
- they tend to fill up and leak memory if not properly handled

Comment: Ok so basically I'd save them there in a static map and could then access them from anywherE? That might work quite well for the moment, so I'm going for this approach. Anyhow I feel that from design point of view, this is not very clean...

Comment: Components registries/caches are a common feature, JNDI, db caches, etc... They are clean when they are well programmed and as the saying goes "There are only two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-1 errors". If you do not want a registry, use the proposed event driven model... but be careful you may soon end-up with a cache of listeners ! :)

Comment: I see. As I only require a couple of grids to be refreshed probably from KISS point of view a cache is prefered solution here.

Answer (score 4):

Just create and fire an [`Event`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/Event.html) for it in your service and make your grid register for that `Event`. It's probably best to use an [`EventBus`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html).

Using a static `Map<String, Grid>` as was suggested in the accepted answer will work but it's not proper. You risk making mistakes and it's not as easy to manage when the number of grids increases.

The `EventBus` approach is more work upfront but in the end it's a better approach. You'll be able to reuse the `EventBus` throughout your application. It really helps keep your coupling down. You'll also easily be able to get different objects act on the same `Event` with little effort.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for not answering that long time, i was in vacation.

Interfaces are some kind of classes.
But they do not implement any method, they have empty method bodies.

Each class, which implements an interface  usually MUST implement its methods.

In C# You would Do :

```
enter code here

    interface IMyInterface
    {
       void PleaseImplementMe();
    }


    class clMyInterface :IMyInterface
    {

        void  IMyInterface.PleaseImplementMe()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("One implementation");
        }    
    }





end
```

Please let me know, whether this is what can help You or not.